# Solving a linear non-separable first order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I'm trying to solve a linear non-separable first order PDE of the form

$$ \nabla f(x,y,z) = g(x,y,z) \mathbf{v}, $$

where $g(x,y,z) = a_{11}x^2+a_{12}xy + \dots=\sum a_{ij}x_ix_j$ with $a_{ij}$ constant coefficients, and $\mathbf{v}$ is a constant vector.

I'm looking for any guidance on how to approach this.

At first, I tried taking the curl on both sides to get $\nabla g \times \mathbf{v}=0$ assuming $\partial_i \partial_j f = \partial_j \partial_i f$, but that implies $\mathbf{v}$ is parallel to $\nabla g$ for all values of $x$, $y$, and $z$, which seems inconsistent with $\mathbf{v}=\text{const.}$ It seems the solution (if any?) might take the form of nonseparable products on the variables, but all I could do so far was unsuccessfully proceed by trial and error.

Comment: Why don't you just integrate term by term directly? \begin{align} \partial_{x} f &= g v_{1} \implies f = v_{1} \int g dx + h_{1}(y,z) \\ \partial_{y} f &= g v_{2} \implies f = v_{2} \int g dy + h_{2}(x,z) \\ \partial_{z} f &= g v_{3} \implies f = v_{3} \int g dz + h_{3}(x,y) \end{align} then find the consistency conditions on the $h_{i}$.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I tried this as well. I may be missing something, but I couldn't find any consistent $h_i$. For instance, in the simple case of $\mathbf{v}$ along the $x$-axis, on one hand I get $f(x,y,z)=v_1\int g dx +h_1(y,z)$ and on the other $f(x,y,z)=h_2(x,z)=h_3(x,y)$, but these are incompatible.

Comment: Well there simply does not exist a solution for arbitrary $v$ and $g$.

Comment: If the consistency conditions don't exist then a solution doesn't exist for arbitrary $v$ and $g$ as maxmilgram stated above.

Comment: That makes sense indeed. I wasn't confident about this conclusion because I was looking for eigenstates $\psi=\ln f$ of the operator $g^{-1}\nabla$ in the physical model I'm working on. Eigenvalues were expected to relate to position coordinates $\mathbf{v}$ (bad notation, sorry) and exist for arbitrary $a_{ij}$ coefficients inside $g$.